# Abrir collapse via URL Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, collapse

Como posso fazer para abrir um determinado collapse via URL?

Por exemplo: ao clicar em *'Link 1'* ele vai para a página *'pagina1'* e abre/leva o usuário para o collapse '*link1'* *(href="pagina1.html#link-1")*, neste caso o collapse está com o ID *link1*

Apenas para ter uma ideia do ambiente, montei uma estrutura básica no JSFiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/wkujfg18/16/

Comment: Seu código está funcionando. Apenas tem umas redundâncias. Vc quer abrir o collapse quando vem de outra página ou é quando clica no link da mesma página?

Comment: Ainda apanho do JS :S.... Teria que ser os dois... Quando o usuário vem de outra página ou quando está na mesma página

Comment: Ele está funcionando em partes, pois se eu tiver um conteúdo (outro ID) dentro do collapse, como faço para redirecionar? No caso ele teria que abrir o collapse e depois levar para o conteúdo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma:

```
$("a.nav-link").click(function(e,i){
   if(i){
      var hash = i.ancora ? i.hash : i;
   }else{
      var hash = this.href.match(/#.+/)[0];
   }

   $(hash + '.collapse').collapse('show');

   if(i) hash = i.ancora || hash;

   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 200 }, 500);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   var hash = location.hash;
   var params = hash;
   if(!$(hash).hasClass('collapse')){
      hash = "#"+$(hash).closest(".collapse").attr("id");
      params = {hash: "#"+$(hash).closest(".collapse").attr("id"), ancora: params};
   }
   if(hash) $("a.nav-link[href$='"+hash+"']").trigger("click", params);
});
```

Se houver o hash na URL ou se você clicar no menu, irá disparar o evento `click` onde irá abrir o collapse.

Comment: E para fazer os links abrirem o collapse e ir para um ID dentro do collapse? Como posso fazer esse tipo de interação?

Comment: OK!, Como não estava na pergunta, vou ver aqui.

Comment: Esse `-200`que vc usa, seria oq? Vc não quer que a div encoste no topo?

Comment: Dei uma atualizada na resposta. Testa aí.

Comment: Desculpe a demora... Fiz algumas alterações no HTML e no JS e deu certo! Agradeço muito a ajuda!

Comment: Sem problemas. Fico contente que tenha dado certo.

Comment: Votei +1 na pergunta, agora vc pode votar tb. Abs!